# Hide Outlook envelope in system tray

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003

When I get a new email in Outlook 2003 I get two notifications; one is the envelope in the system tray, and one is the fading noticiation message in the lower right corner. If I click the notification message, the envelope will never disappear, even if all emails are read.

If Outlook is restarted the envelope disappears. If I right click the envelope and choose "Hide envelope" I have to go into the settings and set the Show envelope option to true again to see the envelope. I want the envelope, but only when there are any unread emails in my inbox. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click the Taskbar and choose Properties. Click Customize. Scroll
down to the "You have new unopened items" icon and change "Always hide" or
"Hide when inactive" to "Always show". Click OK, then OK.

or

Open Outlook > Tools > Options > Preference Tab > E-Mail Options > Advanced
Email Options

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with my Outlook 2003.  The system tray envelope appears and won't disappear when I read a new message, but only when my Outlook hasn't finished retrieving all the new messages yet.

My workaround is to just double-click on any message once all the new messages have finished being downloaded into Outlook, and then the systray envelope disappears.  I know this isn't quite a fix, but the problem may stem from Outlook not downloading all new messages just yet, and there being a delay between me reading the new message(s), and what Outlook is reporting are new message(s).